# WPF ScrollViewer control buttons visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox, which has hidden Horizontal ScrollBar.

I have added custom buttons, to control this scroll (move left/move right).

I would like to hide (set visibility to collapsed) or something if scrollViewer does not contain enough items to work(When all child items fit in screen)

Is it possible in WPF?

EDIT:

Basically my view is kind of complicated, but I have something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedPatients}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient}">
...
...
</ListBox>
```

And I have controls with codebehind:

```
private void ButtonBase1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ListBox);
    _scrollViewer.LineLeft();
    _scrollViewer.LineLeft();
    _scrollViewer.LineLeft();
    _scrollViewer.LineLeft();
    _scrollViewer.LineLeft();
}

private void ButtonBase2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ListBox);
    _scrollViewer.LineRight();
    _scrollViewer.LineRight();
    _scrollViewer.LineRight();
    _scrollViewer.LineRight();
    _scrollViewer.LineRight();

}
```

Comment: Please post your XAML.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to achieve what you want is to restyle the horizontal `ScrollBar` of the `ListBox`'s `ScrollViwer`. You'd have to define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `ScrollViewer` in which you simply substitute the original `ScrollBar` for an edited version of the `ScrollBar` with a custom `ControlTemplate` without the `Track Thumb`, but retaining the original `RepeatButton`s.

You can find the default `ControlTemplate` for the `ScrollViewer` in the [ScrollViewer Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847(v=vs.110).aspx) page and the default `ControlTemplate` for the `ScrollViewer` in the [ScrollBar Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. If you need to, you can find out about `ControlTemplate`s from the [`ControlTemplate` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

As an example, adapted from the first linked page, you'd need to create a custom `ControlTemplate` for the horizontal `ScrollBar` as described above and apply it in a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="LeftScrollViewer"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Border Grid.Column="1"
                  BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <ScrollContentPresenter />
          </Border>
          <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
          <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"

                     Template="{StaticResource YourCustomScrollBarTemplate}"/>

        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you soooo much, you saved me a lot of time with the visibility thing. :D